# Why my code still slow after threading for 15k records only, how to fix this

Tags: python, multithreading, hyperlink

I have a script, taking links from a file, visiting it, getting re-directed links, storing it back. But it works too slow on a file with 15k records. How can I make it quick? already used threading
Please do help to fix it out!, I've tried multiple ways, threadings but I cannot make it quick. Is there any solution to my problem by any chance? any expert who could help me out.

```
import concurrent.futures
import sys
import pandas as pd
import requests
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
out_put_file=""
linkes = None
out = []
urls = []
old = []
file_name =None
concurrent = 10000
q = None
count=0
df =None
def do_work():
    while True:
        global q
        url = q.get()
        res = get_status(url)
        q.task_done()
def get_status(o_url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(o_url)
        if res:
            out.append(res.url)
            old.append(o_url)
        print(count)
        count=count+1
        return [res.status_code,res.url ,o_url]
    except:
        pass
    return [ans.status_code,ans.url,url]
def process_data():
        global q
        global file_name
        global linkes
        global df
        file_name = input("Enter file name : ")
        file_name = file_name.strip()
        print("Generating .......")
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name+".csv")
        old_links =df["shopify"]
        for i in old_links:
            if type(i)!=str:
                urls.append(i)
                continue
            if not i.startswith("http"):
                
                linkes = "http://"+i 
                urls.append(linkes)
            else:
                urls.append(i)
        df["shopify"]=urls
        q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
        for i in range(concurrent):
            t = Thread(target=do_work)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        try:
            for url in urls:
                if type(url)!=str:
                    continue
                q.put(url.strip())
            q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)
process_data()
for i in range (len(df['shopify'])):
    for j in range(len(old)):
        if df['shopify'][i]==old[j]:
            df['shopify'][i]=out[j]
df = df[~df['shopify'].astype(str).str.startswith('http:')]
df = df.dropna()
df.to_csv(file_name+"-new.csv",index=False)
```

```
Email,shopify,Proofy_Status_Name
hello@knobblystudio.com,http://puravidabracelets.myshopify.com,Deliverable
service@cafe-select.co.uk,cafe-select.co.uk,Deliverable
mtafich@gmail.com,,Deliverable
whoopies@stevessnacks.com,stevessnacks.com,Deliverable
customerservice@runwayriches.com,runwayriches.com,Deliverable
shop@blackdogride.com.au,blackdogride.com.au,Deliverable
anavasconcelos.nica@gmail.com,grass4you.com,Deliverable
info@prideandprestigehair.com,prideandprestigehair.com,Deliverable
info@dancinwoofs.com,dancinwoofs.com,Deliverable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the first few lines of the CSV file. Also please don't name a variable the same as a module (`concurrent`) as that can cause problems. By the way, your load_url function is unused.

Comment: I've added that csv file data (10 rows) and yes load_url isn't used, ignore it.

Comment: It still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Threads in Python do not run simultaneously due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython). You might want to use the `multiprocessing` module instead, or `ProcessPoolExecutor()` from concurrent.futures. If you decide to use ProcessPoolExecutors, pass the URLs to the callback and have the callback return the old and redirected URL which should be returned by the `result` method of the future you get from the executor.submit. When using processes, global variables are not shared, unlike threads.

There has been an [attempt](https://lwn.net/Articles/754577/) to remove the global interpreter lock but without the GIL, Python doesn't run quite as fast or something like that if I remember correctly.

Something like the following might work. I renamed the concurrent variable because it would shadow the concurrent module and probably cause an error. <s>This code is untested because I don't have the csv file to test with.</s>

```py
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import sys
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
out_put_file=""
linkes = None
out = []
urls = []
old = []
futures = []
file_name =None
concurrent_ = 10000
q = None
count=0
df =None
def do_work(urls):
    results = []
    for url in urls:
        res = get_status(url)
        if res:
            results.append((res[2], res[1]))
        else:
            results.append((url, url))
    return results
def get_status(o_url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(o_url)
        if res:
            out.append(res.url)
            old.append(o_url)
        #print(count)
        #count=count+1
        return [res.status_code,res.url ,o_url]
    except:
        pass
def load_url(url, timeout):
    ans = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    return [ans.status_code,ans.url,url]
def process_data():
        global q
        global file_name
        global linkes
        global df
        global urls
        file_name = input("Enter file name : ")
        file_name = file_name.strip()
        print("Generating .......")
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name+".csv")
        old_links =df["shopify"]
        for i in old_links:
            if type(i)!=str:
                urls.append(i)
                continue
            if not i.startswith("http"):
                
                linkes = "http://"+i 
                urls.append(linkes)
            else:
                urls.append(i)
        df["shopify"]=urls
        workers = 50
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
            url_arrays = np.array_split(urls, workers)
            for urls in url_arrays:
                f = executor.submit(do_work, urls)
                futures.append(f)
process_data()
df['shopify'] = [res[1] for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures) for res in f.result()]
df = df[~df['shopify'].astype(str).str.startswith('http:')]
df = df.dropna()
df.to_csv(file_name+"-new.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: How can I use multi-processing in this case? can u adjust the code?

Comment: Help me to fix this, took me a lot of time trying different things but cannot make it work.

Comment: The above code kept prompting "filename', it is not going inside the do_work() method. I'm not sure why, it keep asking to enter filename for some unknown reasons.

Comment: It asks to enter the filename like (max_workers) time, max_workers are 50, it will ask 50 times. When I enter the filename, it gives an error "an attempt to run other process while other are already running" something like this.

Comment: I've added 10 rows of my data, if you wish to test it at your side. It would be a csv file.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? It only prompts once every time I run the script on my computer. Did you accidentally write `executor.submit(process_data)`? That won't work and would give the behavior you describe of asking for the filename several times.

Comment: I exactly run the code you sent, its not working at my side, asking me to enter file name again and again, and I didn't write anything to code.